# Implementing "Mobile step progress bar" from the material guidelines

Tags: flutter, material-design, flutter-layout

The material design guidelines used to have a section on steppers: https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/steppers.html#steppers-types-of-steps . This included various stepper types, including "Mobile step progress bar":

[image: Mobile step progress bar pattern]

Flutter has a Stepper class, but very scantily documented. How would I implement the kind of stepper seen above?

There's a [request for documentation on Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11789) that touches on this topic, but so far, there aren't any clear guides on how to implement this.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think Flutter's stepper class is the same stepper you're talking about. It's meant for a completely different purpose.

As for your "stepper", it's actually quite simple to make one yourself. I've done it two ways - one with a LinearProgressIndicator and the other with a simple gradient, but you could also do it pretty easily with a custompaint.

I've included it within a PageView example as that seems to be what you're doing with it. Some of the PageView code is cribbed from the [flutter gallery pagination example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/progress_indicator_demo.dart) and actually that page would probably be worth looking at as well.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  PageController _pageController = new PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: PageView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(child: Text("Page 1")),
            Center(child: Text("Page 2")),
            Center(child: Text("Page 3")),
            Center(child: Text("Page 4")),
          ],
          controller: _pageController,
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 10,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: GradientPageIndicator(
                pageController: _pageController,
                pageCount: 4,
                primaryColor: Colors.blue,
                secondaryColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 10,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: ProgressPageIndicator(
                pageController: _pageController,
                pageCount: 4,
                primaryColor: Colors.blue,
                secondaryColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProgressPageIndicator extends AnimatedWidget {
  final PageController pageController;

  final int pageCount;

  final Color primaryColor;

  final Color secondaryColor;

  final num height;

  ProgressPageIndicator({
    @required this.pageController,
    @required this.pageCount,
    @required this.primaryColor,
    @required this.secondaryColor,
    this.height = 2.0,
  }) : super(listenable: pageController);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: height,
      child: LinearProgressIndicator(
        backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
        valueColor: Tween(begin: primaryColor, end: primaryColor).animate(kAlwaysCompleteAnimation),
        value: (pageController.page ?? pageController.initialPage) / (pageCount - 1),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GradientPageIndicator extends AnimatedWidget {
  final PageController pageController;

  final int pageCount;

  final Color primaryColor;

  final Color secondaryColor;

  final num height;

  GradientPageIndicator({
    @required this.pageController,
    @required this.pageCount,
    @required this.primaryColor,
    @required this.secondaryColor,
    this.height = 2.0,
  }) : super(listenable: pageController);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double pagePosition = (pageController.page ?? pageController.initialPage) / (pageCount - 1);
    double alignPosition = pagePosition * 2 - 1;

    print("PagePosition: $pagePosition, alignPosition: $alignPosition");

    return Container(
      height: height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [primaryColor, secondaryColor],
          begin: Alignment(alignPosition - 0.0001, 0),
          end: Alignment(alignPosition + 0.0001, 0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```